# Plugin "deploy applications" not working in cloudbees / Jenkins

Tags: deployment, amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, cloudbees

I have the Deploy plugin installed in CloudBees Jenkins but when I select "deploy applications" on the job configuration page nothing is happening (i.e. no new input fields are created). Is this a general problem with CloudBees, Jenkins or the Plugin?

What I wanted to achieve is to deploy to AWS Elastic Beanstalk - is there another way?

Best regards,
Joerg

Answer (score 0):

Here's the [documentation](https://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/ElasticBeanstalk) for deploying to Elastic Beanstalk.

Comment: Thank you but I was using this description already. However, the selector shown in picture 4 "Add host Service" is not shown to me.

Comment: OK, probably best to open a support ticket then.